# issues with ajax and javascript when trying to count marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having an issue with my javascript. I am trying to count marks for each correct chosen answer which is determined from db. If incorrect answer then marks is '0', else mark is dependent on answer's mark in db.

But I am having issues with the javascript:

First of all where it says `connect.php`, this just simply navigates to page where it connects to db, but is this correct or am I suppose to link to page where it will run query looking up answer's marks?

Second it says I have undefined `response` in my code and I do not what this should be called.

My question is can I have clarification for the above 2. I am trying to use ajax and javascript and will appreciate if a strong programmer can tackle this issue I am having and be able to correctly set up the code so that it is able to count each correct answer marks.

I have a jsfiddle which I am trying to follow but if somebody can edit fiddle to have a dummy version working for counting marks and then be able to provide code snippet stating what the proper code should be, then this will help me very much.

At moment the jsfiddle determines if answers selected are correct or incorrect and fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bWthd/3/

Actual code:

PHP/HTML:

```
    $qandaquery = "SELECT q.QuestionId, Answer, AnswerMarks, OptionType
                            FROM Question q
                            INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
                            INNER JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
                            WHERE SessionId = ?
                            GROUP BY q.QuestionId
                            ORDER BY RAND()";

        ...

            $qandaqrystmt->bind_result($qandaQuestionId,$qandaAnswer,$qandaAnswerMarks,$OptionType);

            $arrQuestionId = array();


            while ($qandaqrystmt->fetch()) {
            $arrQuestionId[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaQuestionId;

          }

        foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

        ?>

        <div class="queWrap" data-q_id="<?php echo $key; ?>">

        $options = explode('-', $arrOptionType[$key]);
        if(count($options) > 1) {
            $start = array_shift($options);
            $end = array_shift($options);
            do {
                $options[] = $start;
            }while(++$start <= $end);
         }
         else{
            $options = explode(' or ', $option);
         }

    if($arrReplyType[$key] == 'Single'){
     foreach($options as $indivOption) {
         echo '<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="radio"
        name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . 
     $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
     }
     }else if($arrReplyType[$key] == 'Multiple'){
           foreach($options as $indivOption) {
         echo '<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
     }

}

    <p><input type='text' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionId[$key]); ?>' /></p>

    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT/AJAX:**

```
$(function() {

      $('.queWrap .ck-button').change(function() {
        var $ch_box = $(this),
            $qwrap=$ch_box.closest('.queWrap')
            q_id = $qwrap.data('q_id'),
            val = $ch_box.val();

        var dataToServer = {
            q_id: q_id,
            valueSelected: val
        }

$.post('connect.php', dataToServer,function(){ 
        var status=response.status
        $qwrap.find('.status').text( status).addClass(status);
        if( status=='correct'){
            updateScore( response.points)
        }
    })

})

function updateScore( newScore){
    var score= $points.data('score')+newScore;
    $points.data('score',score).text( 'Score: '+score)
}

    });
```

**UPDATE:**

Current code:

```
    function update() {
    var score = 0;
    $('.queWrap').each(function(element) {
        var $qwrap = $(element),
        q_id = $qwrap.data('q_id'),
        val = $qwrap.find('input:checked').val();

                var dataToServer = {
            q_id: q_id,
            valueSelected: val
        }

        $.post('connect.php', dataToServer,function(response){ 
            var status = response.status
            $qwrap.find('.status').text(status).addClass(status);
            if (status == 'correct'){
                score += response.points; 
                $points.data('score', score).text('Score: ' + score);
            }
        })

    });


    }

...
//HTML
<div class="status">&nbsp;</div>
```

Ok there is no errors but there is no marks appearing and calculating. Is it because of the `connect.php` I included in the javascript function. Do I need to navigate to page which connects to db `connect.php` or navigate to a page where it runs a query on finding answer marks for each selected answer? I am running out of time so can you please implement the code for me asap because I have to get this finished. I want the following to happen:

- Count marks for each answer selected, if incorrect answer selected then value is `0` for those answers, if correct answer then it's marks are determined from database. Howcan I get each correct answer button to contain it's own answerId?
- To determine answerId we can use the questionId displayed in text input (See PHP/HTML code snippet at top) and then depending on values of each answer button, retrieve the answerid matching the answer values for each question.

Below is example database showing `Answer Table`

```
AnswerId (auto PK)  QuestionId  Answer  AnswerMarks
1                   72          A        2
2                   72          C        1
3                   73          B        2
4                   73          C        2
5                   73          E        1
```

Comment: I think you have to put a parameter in the callback, like this: `$.post('connect.php', dataToServer,function(response){ `

Comment: @Kaeros It has removed the response error but now giving me error on this line: $qwrap.find('.status').text( status).addClass(status); and error is: $qwrap.find(...).text(..).addClass is not a function. I deal more with oracle/sql programming than client side programming so apologies in advance for asking questions on specific errors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updateScore function works wrong. You should store the points for each question in a data element, and in the updateScore() function you should add all these up, and put the sum into the $points element. Something like this:

```
$(function() {

    $('.queWrap .ck-button').change(function() {
        update();
    });

    function update() {
        var score = 0;
        $('.queWrap').each(function(element) {
            var $qwrap = $(element);
            var q_id = $qwrap.data('q_id');
            var val = $qwrap.find('input:checked').val();

            var dataToServer = {
                q_id: q_id,
                valueSelected: val
            };

            $.post('connect.php', dataToServer, function(response){ 
                var status = response.status
                $qwrap.find('.status').text(status).addClass(status);
                if(status == 'correct'){
                    score += response.points; 
                    $points.data('score', score).text('Score: ' + score);
                }
            });  
        });

    }

}
```

And this function should be invoked on every change of the answers. (I am not sure this works just an example).

Comment: Hi, if you do not mind can you show a code snippet example on your solution?

Comment: Hi, there are other problems too. For example multiple answers can be checked per question, but it seems like you only send one selected value to the server. This is controversial. If you want to allow only one answer per question, you should use radio button instead of checkboxes. Or if you want to allow multiple answers, you have to deal with all of them when you check the correctness.

Comment: Hi, Yeah I actually do have the code where if single option only then radio buttons else if multiple then checkboxes. I just tried to limit code. Do you want me to include code where it checks for single or multiple selection?

Comment: I updated code in update to show multiple and single options selection

Comment: How are you finding it? if you need more info please comment to me :)

Comment: As the marks are coming from the database, aren't I suppose to change the line beginning with `$.post...` to something else? Thanks for code snippet btw :)

Comment: I don't understand you. The marks are coming from the database, therefore you have to get them with an ajax call. That's what you do with the $.post I don't see any reason to change that.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a test, sorry I did not explain myself clearly, what I meant was that am I suppose to change `createDummyAjaxResponse(q_id, val)` to something else such s `dataServer` in my code?

Comment: Yes you are supposed to change that, because that's a dummy. I just took it from your code, as an example.

Comment: Let me post an update explaining what is currently happening. Give me 5 mins

Comment: Update included, I really need this to be resolved asap because I am running out of time. Any help is appreciated and if you can solve this fully I will set up a bounty after your solution and give you extra points but I do need a full solution asap, really need your co-operation